# How to trigger a job in every 5 min in while loop?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have a requirement to check some variables every 5 minutes within a while loop. The while loop executes other stuff too, but in that duration it has to execute [code] every 5 min. can anyone suggest me good solution to it?

```
while (1) {
 <execute something all the time>
# Check the time, if it is 5 minutes passed then execute the below code
[code]

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $nextruntime=0;

while(1){
   # Other stuff
   if(time()>=$nextruntime){
      print "Doing 5 minute stuff...\n";
      # do your 5 minute stuff
      $nextruntime=time()+300;
   }
   print "Waiting for Godot...\n";
   sleep 1;
}
```

Change the "my $nextruntime=0;" into "my $nextruntime=time()+300;" if you don't want to do your other stuff immediately the program starts but only after initial 5 minutes have lapsed.

Comment: And change `$nextruntime=time()+300;` to `$nextruntime=nextruntime+300;` to avoid drifting.

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`alarm`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#alarm) function:

```
my $foo = 0;
local $SIG{ALRM} = sub {
    say($foo);
    alarm(1);
};

alarm(1);
while (1) {
    $foo++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my $next_5min_sec = time() + 5 * 60;

while(1)
{
    # some other stuff

    $t = time();

    if ($t >= $next_5min_sec)
    {
        $next_5min_sec += 5 * 60;

        # do your 5 minute stuff here
    }

    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: time(now) is not valid